# Drupal blocks vs. content types

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm just getting started with Drupal and I'm trying to implement a piece of content that states "A first generation family farm, Wheat Ridge, CO" and then immediately afterwards displays 4 social media icons. see image.

[image: This is a link to an image depicting what I am trying to show.]

And I don't know what the best way to implement this piece of content is. Should it be a black, a content type, or something else completely? And what's the best way to reference the images in drupal?

I've never worked within a content management system before so any help would be greatly appreciated.

~Austin

Comment: Never have images of text. It's a violation against accessibility plus it's just annoying.

Comment: I should seriously hope thats a given. I said this was my first CMS usage not my first website. I just screen captured my mockup to illustrate what I was trying to do.

Comment: Cool, can't blame me for pointing it out, it's way too common to see this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Austin - It largely depends on wether the content editor of the website needs access to update that content.  If so, creating a content type and then displaying that information in view block would be the way to go. You could also use an iconfont for the social media links and avoid images all together.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this piece of content never changes, I would create a small block for

```
A first generation family farm | Wheatridge, CO
```

...and a Drupal menu for the 3 social networks links, opening in a new window (on menu link edit page), with text hidden in CSS (text-indent:-9999px on 'a' tags), proper titles for tooltips, and icons in background image (CSS). You can use [Drupal Menu Attribute](https://drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) to add ids or classes to your menu items and generate something like

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="drupal default classes"><a href="..." class="fb-link">FB</a></li>
  <li class="drupal default classes"><a href="..." class="tw-link">TW</a></li>
  <li class="drupal default classes"><a href="..." class="pi-link">PI</a></li>
</ul>
```

...and be able to assign proper background-image to your 'a' in CSS. Then you'll just have to put your block and your new menu block in the right region of your theme and adjust CSS. A content type would definitely be overkill.